# OwnCloud and mindlna in same folder (law-management) - minidlna.c:474: error: Media directory not accessible! [Permission denied]

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, owncloud

I have a question about my configuration and the permissions in my Raspi B with minidlna and owncloud.

I have set my user pi with the permission

> dmask=007 aka 0770 on every start 
>   because it is a
>
> ntfs usb-hdd 
>   that can only set with the permissions in
>
> /etc/fstab

there stands

> sudo nano /etc/fstab
>
> UUID=3488A17988A139EE /media/usb-hdd ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,windows_names 0 0
>
> uid=1000 -> for the user pi
>
> gid=1000 -> for the group pi

because I got the failure via owncloud in my browser

> Data directory ( /media/USB-HDD/ownCloud/data ) can be read by other users
>   Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory can not be viewed by others

now with this dmask=007 it work probably for me

Now my problem:

I have also put my folder with the media content Movies, ... under this path

> /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies

but with the order

> sudo -u minidlna minidlna -R

I got same failures:

> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] minidlna.c:474: error:
>
> Media directory "/media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies" not accessible! [Permission denied]
>
> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] getifaddr.c:73: error: ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, ...): No such device

My minidlna.conf contains this

> sudo nano /etc/minidlna.conf
>
> [2015/06/17 19:42:29] playlist.c:125: warn: Parsing playlists...
>
> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] daemonize.c:101: error: Unable to open pidfile for writing /run/minidlna.pid: Permission denied
>
> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] minidlna.c:898: warn: Starting MiniDLNA version 1.0.24 [SQLite 3.7.13].
>
> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] minidlna.c:926: warn: Creating new database...
>   [2015/06/17 19:55:31] minidlna.c:132: error: bind(http): Address already in use
>
> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] minidlna.c:1004: fatal: Failed to open socket for HTTP. EXITING
>
> [2015/06/17 19:55:31] playlist.c:125: warn: Parsing playlists...
>
> [2015/06/17 20:11:30] minidlna.c:155: warn: received signal 15, good-bye
>
> [2015/06/17 20:11:52] minidlna.c:898: warn: Starting MiniDLNA version 1.0.24 [SQLite 3.7.13].
>
> [2015/06/17 20:11:52] minidlna.c:1006: warn: HTTP listening on port 8200
>
> [2015/06/17 20:11:52] inotify.c:195: warn: WARNING: Inotify max_user_watches [8192] is low or close to the number of used watches [0] and I do not hav$
>
> [2015/06/18 04:44:57] daemonize.c:101: error: Unable to open pidfile for writing /run/minidlna.pid: Permission denied
>
> [2015/06/18 04:44:57] minidlna.c:898: warn: Starting MiniDLNA version 1.0.24 [SQLite 3.7.13].
>
> [2015/06/18 04:44:57] minidlna.c:926: warn: Creating new database...
>
> [2015/06/18 04:44:57] minidlna.c:132: error: bind(http): Address already in use
>
> [2015/06/18 04:44:57] minidlna.c:1004: fatal: Failed to open socket for HTTP. EXITING
>   [2015/06/18 04:44:57] playlist.c:125: warn: Parsing playlists...

The permissions are

> pi@WoW /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies $ 
>   ls -ld /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies
>
> drwxrwx--- 1 pi pi 4096 Jun 16 22:04 /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud
>
> drwxrwx--- 1 pi pi 4096 Jun  1 00:30 /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies

Is it possible the set the permissions of

> /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/ to 0770
>
> and to the folder
>
> /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies
>
> other permissions, so that can access minidlna to it.

Or have I to move the folder /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies

> to /media/usb-hdd/Movies

The reason is I will observe the folder

> /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/
>
> via owncloud and share the folder Movies intern to my Samsung TV via DNLA.

So I found @ https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=16352&sid=1150f7e92b864c89979fc4c39a34639b&start=25

> under the point I changed the GID of the user minidlna since it can't run as pi (only root or minidlna)

the following info

before

> pi@Wow:/$ id minidlna
>
> uid=108(minidlna) gid=112(minidlna) groups=112(minidlna)

I change the permissions to the user mindlna user after this

> pi@WoW:/$ sudo usermod -g 1000 minidlna

Now I have

> pi@WoW ~ $ id minidlna
>   uid=108(minidlna) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi)

with the order

> pi@WoW ~ $ sudo -u minidlna minidlna -R
>
> [2015/06/18 06:03:39] getifaddr.c:73: error: ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, ...): No such                                           device

But What is this

> getifaddr.c:73: error: ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, ...): No such                                           device

But now I get this

> pi@WoW ~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/minidlna restart
>   [....] Restarting DLNA/UPnP-AV media server: minidlna[2015/06/18 06:40:09] minidlna.c:474: error:
>
> Media directory "/media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies" not accessible! [Permission denied
>
> [2015/06/18 06:40:09] getifaddr.c:73: error: ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, ...): No such device
>   . ok
>   pi@WoW ~ $

with

> pi@WoW ~ $ ls -ld /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Movies
>
> drwxrwx--- 1 pi pi 4096 Jun 16 22:04 /media/usb-hdd/OwnCloud/data/admin/files/Filme

What is wrong!

Now I have changed the value umask=0002

> > /etc/fstab

there stands

> sudo nano /etc/fstab
>
> UUID=3488A17988A139EE /media/usb-hdd ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,umask=0002,windows_names 0 0

ANd the order

> pi@WoW ~ $ sudo service minidlna force-reload
>   [....] Restarting DLNA/UPnP-AV media server: minidlna[2015/06/18 08:11:24] getifaddr.c:73: error: ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, ...): No such device
>   . ok

But the failure

> getifaddr.c:73: error: ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, ...): No such device

is also there.

Here I search till now for a solution!

Comment: I suggest you move your solution to the answer section.